# Click link only when another link is available/when all data is loaded on page in python-selenium-firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I tried below 2 ways to wait before clicking button, but I am getting an error. I want to wait until anchor text `stored query` is available.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ANCHOR,"stored query")))
driver.find_element_by_link_text("[Comma-Delimited Text (CSV)]").click()
```

or:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("path"), "stored query"));
driver.find_element_by_link_text("[Comma-Delimited Text (CSV)]").click()
```

Error:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("path"), "stored query"));
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'until'
```

Comment: `By.ANCHOR` is it valid?

Comment: Where do you define `wait`? Maybe you are missing an import?

Comment: Also tried: `WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[starts-with(@href,"javascript:self.opener.parent.openS` but error `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ` Though I could see that link was present before timeout.

Comment: @SSG, was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Comment: @Ratmir AsanovAs, I got it working with other `id`, so didn't try. But thank you your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I just went thru web page again searching any element that has `id` and found one `form`. 
My final code for just waiting page is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
# Some code for loading web page            
WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "call_list")))
# Hit button/ perform next action
driver.find_element_by_link_text("[Comma-Delimited Text (CSV)]").click()
```